# transfer object ownership with placement new

Tags: c++, ownership, placement-new

I have a Visual Studio 2008 C++ project with a class that manages a resource that cannot be copied. I have implemented transfer-by-reference-structure semantics (ala `std::auto_ptr`).

```
class Test;

struct Test_Ref
{
    Test& ref_;
    Test_Ref( Test& t ) : ref_( t ) { };
private:
    Test_Ref& operator=( Test_Ref const& );
}; // struct Test_Ref

class Test
{
public:
    explicit Test( int f = 0 ) : foo_( f ) { };

    Test( Test& other ) : foo_( other.Detach() ) { };

    Test& operator=( Test& other )
    {
        foo_ = other.Detach();
        return *this;
    };

    Test( Test_Ref other ) : foo_( other.ref_.Detach() ) { };

    Test& operator=( Test_Ref other )
    {
        foo_ = other.ref_.Detach();
        return *this;
    };

    operator Test_Ref() { return Test_Ref( *this ); };

private:

    int Detach()
    {
        int tmp = foo_;
        foo_ = 0;
        return tmp;
    };

    // resource that cannot be copied. 
    int foo_;
}; // class Test
```

Unfortunately, when I use this pattern with a library that uses placement-new, I get a compiler error:

```
.\test.cpp(58) : error C2558: class 'Test' : no copy constructor available or copy constructor is declared 'explicit'
    .\test.cpp(68) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void Copy<Test>(T *,const T &)' being compiled
    with
    [
        T=Test
    ]
```

For example:

```
template< class T > inline void Copy( T* p, const T& val ) 
{
    new( p ) T( val );
}

int _tmain( int /*argc*/, _TCHAR* /*argv*/[] )
{
    Test* __p = new Test();
    Test __val;
    Copy( __p, __val );
    return 0;
}
```

How can I modify `Test` such that it can be used with placement new and still retain its ownership semantics?

Thanks,
PaulH

Comment: Avoid names that start with double underscores, as those are reserved for the implementation (compiler+standard library). Also the change from `Test *p = NULL;` to `Test *p = new Test();` does not solve the undefined behavior, it just trades it for another (it is UB to construct the same object twice, in your code you are allocating memory and calling the constructor in `main`, then calling the constructor again in `Copy` (and never destructing or releasing the memory...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Focusing on the `main` function, as that should indicate your intended semantics, there are two big problems: First, you are not allocating memory, which means that if the compiler would process the code, it would cause UB (would try to call the constructor of `Test` over the `NULL` address in the placement new operation.

The other issue is well known to users of `std::auto_ptr`: The signature of the copy constructor takes a non-const reference, and that means that you cannot call it on a const object. On the other end you are trying to call the copy constructor inside the `Copy` template that *promised* not to change the object referenced by the second argument:

```
template <typename T>
void Copy( T* p, T& o ) {
   new (p) T( o );         // would work, object is non-const
}
```

Finally, I am not sure if due to copying into the question, but I am not sure of what your intentions are with the reference wrapper class that you are providing in the beginning, so you might want to clarify.

Comment: Ugh. I was so focused on the strange and mysterious placement-new, I completely missed the giant blinking `const` right above it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem has nothing to do with placement new. In `void Copy` then you attempted to copy an object of type Test, but you disallow copying. That's the problem. Also, you attempted to placement new on NULL. You failed to implement the structure properly because of the constness- `operator test_ref()` can never be called because you took a `const T&` and it's a non-const operator. This means that unless you want to surprise people with moves when they think it should be copies, you cannot do this.

Comment: Fixed the placement new on NULL.

Comment: Yes, the goal of this object is to perform moves when copies are specified. Similar to `std::auto_ptr`.